# Very slow compile / run times with XCode for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, build

I've got a project with lots of very large media assets totalling several gigabytes. Build / download / run times are very slow, even when I change nothing. A clean build / download / run on iPad can take 20 minutes but even just debugging with no changes can take 5 minutes or more. It seems the bottleneck is at the point where it determines what new assets need copying. Removing most of the assets speeds up the build / download / run cycle. My current workaround is to build with assets, remove them from the project, and as assets are not cleaned up from the device I can work with the quick build times as long as I don't need asset updates.

I presume other people have had this issue before and I wondered what fixes / workarounds people have.

I have a few ideas, none of which I've researched enough to know if they are viable or not.

1) Have 2 projects, 1 with assets the other with code, both using the same app ID so they both compile to the same app folder on the device. Use the asset build when assets change and the code build for general working.

2) Jailbreak my iPad so I can download assets directly into the app folder as needed and just build code

3) Use placeholder assets that are tiny and test occasionally with real assets.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have the data as application assets. Copy them into app `Documents` folder or some other folder which can be accessed by the app (e.g. temporary folder).

Comment: Exactly. If your assets don't change often, put them in a user-side folder (at least during development time). There is also a very useful option in Xcode Run schemes called "Application Data", where you can choose a snapshot ".xcappdata" of the user directory to be uploaded in the application when you run it (you create these data from the Organizer from a known state), should you have to update those data.

Comment: I've been writing iOS apps for 3 years now and had no idea you could use organizer to upload things to the apps documents folder! That worked great. I can just upload when data changes and compile my app with no data at all for development.

Many thanks